# Repeat DIV Horizontally to make dashed line

Tags: css

I have this CSS:

```
#dotted_line {
    width:80px;
    height:5px;
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
    background:#666666;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

i want to be able to repeat it horizontally so i get a dash line but with long dashes

Comment: post what you have tried first

Comment: and prepare some jsfiddle example.

Comment: You do realise there's an element just for this purpose, called a Horizontal Rule - or `<hr>`?

Comment: make your selector a class selector, use float, and add as many of these divs you need in your HTML.

Comment: ok so example of what i have tried is above..... 

@DannyBeckett i have tried a horizontal rule but couldnt get this to work how i wanted

Comment: @Bartdude i want to be able to just use the one DIV in my HTML if possible

Comment: why don't you use border of element with style dotted?

Comment: @Charlie : then use an image. you're thinking of very complicated solutions to a very simple problem...

Comment: I think @Bartdude is closest to a working solution here, no way to control the dashes' length in css (that i know of)

Comment: Why not using CSS property : `border-style: dashed` ?

Comment: @adenoyelle This way you don't create dash 80px long and 5px height.

Comment: Why are so many people not reading the `with long dashes`part of the question ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `background-image` with the same color as your body background and give the impression of a dashed line. See this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/C9662/1/).

Image used:
[image]

---

If you want to experiment, there's a CSS property that gives you the ability to use an element (your div in this case) as a `background-image`. This property is the `background:element()`.

You can see a [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kpqt/1/) in Firefox.

However, this property works only in Mozilla with the `-moz-` prefix but there have been attempts to implement in webkit browsers as well. So, hopefully this can be implemented in the future with wider browser support.

Comment: Yep, there are no any CSS means of controlling style of dashes. Only by using `background-image` with pattern you need.

Comment: @otinanai Can't vote up you more for that background element (only FF, but anyways great finding)  :)

Comment: Actually, you can use `border-image` but support of this is also not well supported. http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image
EDIT: IE doesn't support this.

Comment: @otinanai That's not true, as stated in my post (recent update) you can control the space between dashes by overlaying 2 divs. It's not the prettiest thing in the world but if you REALLY want to get it done and not use an image....

Answer (score 5):

This is an alternate solution to your problem:

css:

```
.dashed {
    margin:auto;
    width:50%;
    border-style:dashed none none none;
    transform: scaleX(2);
}
```

html:

```
<div class="dashed"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LkVxp/ or http://jsfiddle.net/LkVxp/1/

So what we do is take a border of a div and scale it up so that you can make the dashes longer. just be sure to match the percent to the scale or the width becomes something other than 100% (or you can tweak it to however long you want). Thickness can be controlled normally with `border-width`.

If you wish to make the space between the dashes shorter it will take a bit more work, You'd want to position a second dashed border relatively and offset it however much you want to reduce the space by. So that the offset one would overlap the open space. At that point you're probably just better off using an image though >.>

heres an example: http://jsfiddle.net/LkVxp/3/

More on topic, it isn't a hard task using javascript(jquery or other) to duplicate a dom element.

Comment: Interesting example of use `transform` and `scaleX`.

Comment: The same code renders more space between the dashes on firefox. How can I make it browser compatible?

Comment: Not really sure, if Firefox renders it's dashes differently there's likely not a way to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **hr** tag which can take various attributes, although be warned these are deprecated. For example:

```
<hr>
<hr width="50%">
<hr align="left" width="50%">
```

Comment: You can style it as normal; nothing deprecated about CSS.

Comment: But OP wants to control *the size of the dashes* in the dashed line, i don't think that's possible with css alone (yet).

Comment: Then why do you post deprecated solution? Oh, and tags are not closed too, BTW. Use this instead: `<hr style="width:50%" />`, etc.

Comment: Well it's only depreciated in HTML4, browsers will be supporting it for many years, probably longer than the OP's app will run. I did note it was deprecated, and therefore you didn't need to downvote, especially as you have repeated the code in your own post. Peace. ;-)